# Rails 3.1 AJAX supported changes not reflected in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Running Rails 3.1 Ruby 1.92

I am trying to get my shopping cart to update using AJAX. I have the following button in my store front to create a line item

```
 <%= button_to " Buy ", line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true, :class =>"blue-btn" %>
```

and the following create action in my line_items controller

```
def create
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
respond_to do |format|
 if @line_item.save
 format.html { redirect_to store_url,notice: 'your item was added.' } 
 format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
 format.json { render json: @line_item,
 status: :created, location: @line_item }
```

lastly i have the following RJS code in a create.js.erb template located in my app/views/line_items directory:

```
 $('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
```

However when i add items to the cart i have to refresh the page in order to see the updated quantity and total. I checked the server logs after each attempt to add an item to the cart and its showing that it rendered line_items/create.js.erb Ive included the full log below any help would be much appreciated

Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-04 14:01:26 -0400
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2TxUMUloihqhzGHlZrC9YKNPGNhfwZ070lEW64uL0SY=", "product_id"=>"1"}
  ←[1m←[35mCart Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 64]]
  ←[1m←[36mProduct Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id"
, "1"]]
  ←[1m←[35mLineItem Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = 64 AND "line_
items"."product_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "line_items" ("cart_id", "created_at", "order_id", "product_id", "quantity", "upda
ted_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cart_id", 64], ["created_at", Sun, 04 Aug 2013 18:01:26 UTC +00:00], ["order_id", n
il], ["product_id", 1], ["quantity", 1], ["updated_at", Sun, 04 Aug 2013 18:01:26 UTC +00:00]]
  ←[1m←[36m (103.3ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLineItem Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = 64
  ←[1m←[36mProduct Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mProduct Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (21.0ms)
  Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (22.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 136ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 106.3ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went back and reviewed the ajax steps turns out i was calling the wrong html element. fixed that one issue and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but here are my thoughts:

- I'm not sure about the internals of your `@cart.add_product(...)` method, the code looks like it returns the updated complete cart object (with the added product), correct?
- In the browser (with Firebug or whatever), do you see the server sending you the HTML snippet that is supposed to be inserted?

Comment: not sure how to use firebug to check it do you know of any tutorials on how to go about doing this?